# Develop a workflow for an object where +1 will be added to a number field everytime a record is saved or editted. Can anyone help?

Tags: workflow

I want to Develop an object where +1 will be added to a number field, everytime a record is saved or editted. Can anyone help ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flow not Updating Records](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/106939/flow-not-updating-records)

Comment: No, it doesn't. I am trying to develop a workflow.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I flagged this post as a given duplicate by mistake and forgot about the comment generated automatically.

Answer (score 3):

It is pretty simple to do:

1. Setup -> Workflow & Approvals -> Workflow Rules -> New Rule.
2. Select your object. Add rule name. Evaluate the rule when a record is: **created, and every time it's edited**. Rule criteria should be always true, so I suggest to use *formula evaluates to true* `true`.
3. Add Workflow Action -> New Field Update. Set Name, Field to Update.
4. Specify New Field Value -> Use a formula to set the new value -> `BLANKVALUE(Your_field_name__c, 0) + 1`.
5. Activate the rule.

Comment: +1 `1=1` is shorter, but I think it'd be a little more "obvious" if you just used the formula `true`.

Comment: Also: `BLANKVALUE(Your_field_name__c,0)+1`

Comment: Updated the answer regarding your comments, thank you!